# Getting a array as a result when the result should be an Map?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use MAP into node.js program and I am getting final result however its in array but I need in map. I have write some code to use map but its not working as expected.

Please find below program

```
function CreateProduceMVPRateAsset(data, callback) {
    var ProducePRICE = {};

    var MVPPRICE = [];
    var MVPPRICE_BS = {};
    var MVPPRICE_LB = {};
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);
    console.log('Data', data);
    console.log('Username', data.username);
    var PRODUCENAME = data.PRODUCE;

    var COUNTRY = data.COUNTRY;
    var STATE = data.STATE;
    var MVPRATES = data.MVPRATES;
    console.log('MVPRATERATE', MVPRATES);
    // here I need help
    const MVPRATE = new Map(MVPRATES);

    for (const [k, v] of MVPRATE.entries()) {
        console.log('Inside map', k, v);
        MVPPRICE = v.RATE; // should go in  MVPPRICE

        var Value = MVPPRICE[0].value; // want to get first element value from MVPPRICE array
        console.log('Value', Value);

        var value_lb = Value / 40;
        console.log('value_lb', value_lb);

        value_lb = Number(value_lb.toFixed(4));

        console.log('If the value of BS provided controller come here');

        MVPPRICE_LB.Value = value_lb;
        MVPPRICE_LB.QuantityUnit = 'LB';
        MVPPRICE_LB.uidisplay = false;
        MVPPRICE_LB.CurrencyUnit = 'USD';

        MVPPRICE.push(MVPPRICE_LB);
        ProducePRICE.MVPPRICE = MVPPRICE;

        ProducePRICE.PRODUCENAME = PRODUCENAME;
        ProducePRICE.STATE = STATE;
        ProducePRICE.COUNTRY = COUNTRY;
        console.log('ProducePRICE', ProducePRICE); // whatever result getting it should be map however getting in array.
    }
}
```

JSON structure which I am sending using postman

```
{
"username": "admin2",
  "PRODUCE": "Apple",
  "STATE": "MI",
  "COUNTRY": "US",
  "MVPRATES": {
    "fuji": {
      "VARIETY": "fuji",
      "RATE": [
        {
          "UNIT": "Bussel",
          "CURRENCY": "USD",
          "VALUE": 10.25,
          "UIDISPLAY": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "gala": {
      "VARIETY": "gala",
      "RATE": [
        {
          "UNIT": "Bussel",
          "CURRENCY": "USD",
          "VALUE": 10.25,
          "UIDISPLAY": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Output which I am getting:

[image]

Comment: I personally don't get the question at all, could you be more specific? Do you want to use the Array.map() function? And what has the data sent through Postman got to do with this?

Comment: sorry @ poepje I am new to node.js I never used map in node.js I am confused why I am getting the array in result in ProducePrice, however I want Map in that. I don't know how I can get it like use  Array.map() function

Comment: You are getting a map. the key is `MVPRATE` and the value is an array of rates.

Comment: If I understand you correctly... Array.map() is a function in which you loop through an array. Usage is like `myArray.map((item, index) => { // do something })`. You can also return something (per each iteration) within the function to make a new array out of the result of that function

Comment: Hi @ ktilcu yes right

Comment: @Abhirock where exactly are you getting an array instead of a map?

Comment: Hi @ Sudhakar RS in  console.log('ProducePRICE',ProducePRICE); // whatever result getting it should be map however getting in array.

Comment: @Abhirock ProducePRICE is an object and you are getting it as object only

Comment: which has 'MVPPRICE ', 'PRODUCENAME ', 'STATE' & 'COUNTRY' attributes

Comment: Please post a shorter, more concise reproduction case. strip out whatever is not relevent to the question.
REmember also that array.map does not produce a map - it is named such because it maps a value to a value. The output is an array.

Comment: Hey @Abhirock, if you look at your JSON, the value for RATE is an array. I don't think MAP is recursively turning your values into maps. Also, if you can control the JSON you're receiving - I think it would be better to remove it from an array. It's not clear why it's an an array format.

Comment: @poepje Please see MDN for Map:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Thanks all I got the issue as mentioned @pinkwaffles

Comment: Map returns an array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), not a map (I suppose you mean an object)

Answer (score 1):

@SudhakarRS is right, you're getting your MAP back, you're just getting your values in an array for MVPRATE, and it almost looks like that was your intention, seeing you push here:

```
MVPPRICE.push(MVPPRICE_LB);
```

I mentioned in the comments, but I think what's happening is the Map doesn't apply recursively, so when it sees MVPPRICE, it's treating your value array, as the value instead of part of the map.

I think what you're trying to do can be solved by this:

```
MVPPRICE.concat(MVPPRICE_LB);
ProducePRICE.MVPPRICE = new Map(MVPPRICE)
```